# remove leading whitespace from all lines in a script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am just getting started using the Jenkinsfile pipeline syntax so this is probably something I overlooked on the function guide. I have a step with a script in it that runs a text block as a powershell script, it works fine as it is but I would like to format the file with leading white-space to get everything to line up BUT have the actual executed code have the white-space trimmed. Mainly my pain point is the "@ line where powershell requires it to not have leading white-space so it is sitting out all my itself lonely.

```groovy
script {
  def ps_out = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '''
                $pass = "$env:Remoting_Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
                $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("$env:Remoting_Username",$pass)

                $scriptBlock = @"
                  if (-Not(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name=\'$env:ServiceName\'"))
                  {
                    If ((Get-Service $env:ServiceName).Status -eq 'Running') {
                      Stop-Service -Name $env:ServiceName
                    }
                  }
    "@
                $sb = [scriptblock]::Create($scriptBlock)
                Write-Output "--Script block Start--"
                Write-Output $sb.ToString()
                Write-Output "--Script block End--"
                $sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName $env:TargetServer -Credential $Cred
                Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock $sb
                Remove-PSSession -Session $sess
              ''')
  println ps_out
}
```

Comment: @mkobit you are correct, I searched for whitespace and white-space but overlooked indent.

Comment: Some of the Groovy added extension methods can be difficult to find and search for. Like going through [this Groovydoc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.13/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html) could be painful if you don't know what you are looking for. As a side note, new (ish) versions of Jenkins Pipelines should have that method whitelisted by default (from the [Script Security plugin source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/generic-whitelist#L443-L444).